# How to put Text over the Image in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore

I need to create user control where `<sc:text/>` element should showed over the `<sc:image>`.

I know this can be achieved via CSS but in this case control cannot be configured as we cannot override inline styles.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using the `sc:fld` extension function and wrapping `sc:text` in markup, adding class names or ids (or inline styles if you must!).

```html
<img src="{sc:fld( 'graphic', $sc_currentitem, 'src’ )}" class="head" />
<span class="txt"><sc:text field="txtField" /></span>
```

You can then style these as normal

```css
img.head {}
span.txt {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the problem. This seems like more of a front-end problem than a Sitecore issue. CSS will work fine. Here's a rough example (not tested but gets you the idea):

Sample HTML:

```html
<div class="my-container">
  <div class="img">
    <sc:image Field="Bar" runat="server" />
  </div>
  <div class="txt">
    <sc:text Field="Foo" runat="server" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Sample CSS:

```css
.my-container {
  position: relative;
}

  .my-container .txt {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 50;
    top: 0px;
  }

  .my-container .img {
    z-index: 10;
  }
```

Comment: Should this CSS put in the user control source? Can it be overrode in hosted page?

Comment: You can put it where you want. In the control is fine.